# Replace part of string with values in other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to replace a part of string in "input1" with values in column "input2" to get the "output" as shown:

[image]

Any idea how to do this in MS excel?

Comment: What have you researched and tried yourself so far? It's also good to include what version of Excel you have got.

Answer (score 2):

Try below formula-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"replace_this",B2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the REPLACE and SUBSTITUTE function, if you just need to add something before and/or after some other value (as shown in your picture), you could just use simple concatenation:

```
="Text-before-value" & B2 & "Text-after-value"
```

Answer (score 0):

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Input1 | input2 | output |
| 2 | abc_'replace_this' xyz | replace1 | =REPLACE(A2,FIND("replace_this",A2,1),LEN("replace_this"),B2) |